# Verb for getting in a car accident

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an appropriate verb that can accurately describe getting into a car accident? Saying that someone was 'struck' or 'victimized', just doesn't seem right. (The family was _______ on their way home from the party) I know you can technically just say that someone 'got into a car crash', but I'm hoping there is a verb that can describe getting into such an accident.

Comment: Sometimes there's not a single word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_collision) offers a set of nouns, but most seem to require a verb like to *be*/*have*/etc. .

> Many different terms are commonly used to describe vehicle collisions. The World Health Organization use the term **road traffic injury**, while the U.S. Census Bureau uses the **term motor vehicle accidents (MVA)**, and Transport Canada uses the term **"motor vehicle traffic collision" (MVTC)**. Other common terms include **auto accident**, **car accident**, **car crash**, **car smash**, **car wreck**, **motor vehicle collision (MVC)**, **personal injury collision (PIC)**, **road accident**, **road traffic accident (RTA)**, **road traffic collision (RTC)**, **road traffic incident (RTI)**, **road traffic accident** and later **road traffic collision**, as well as more unofficial terms including **smash-up, pile-up, and fender bender**.

So I guess you could say : *The family **crashed/smashed/collided/RTC-ed** on their way home from the party*, but none of those sound 'right' to me.

Answer (score -1):

The usual construction is, "The family was in a traffic accident," or "The family was involved in a traffic accident."

If you know specifics, you could say, "The family was rear-ended at a stoplight" or "The family spun their car in the snow and hit a tree."

I friend of mine once, totally innocently, came into work one morning and said he'd been "rear-ended by a gay guy." We got a laugh.

Comment: As @Reg Dwight has said, '[W]e write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer.'